# How to make static buttons around the number?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to programming so can't get maybe a simple thing. 
I have 2 buttons with "+" and "-" and a value between them that they change. The problem is that the buttons are moving apart when a new decimal place is added. 
My question is: What can I use to fix the buttons at a certain distance?

```js
var valueS = $('.countSession')[0];
valueS.innerHTML = '0';

var valueS = $('.countSession')[0];
$("#minusS").click(function() {
  valueS.innerHTML--;
  if (valueS.innerHTML < 1) {
    valueS.innerHTML = '0';
  }
})


$("#plusS").click(function() {
  valueS.innerHTML++;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" id="minusS" >-</button>

<span class="countSession"></span>

<button class="button" id="plusS" >+</button>
```

Comment: Do you have a max number of decimal places in mind? The number is going to grow higher at the request of the user, so unless we know the max number creating a "fixed" layout where they don't move dynamically is pretty much impossible. Unless you want them below or above the number - or anywhere other than wrapping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS, you can give it a fixed width that is unlikely to be exceeded. So, for example, if the largest value your application supports is 1000, give the class enough with to allow for 1000.

In the snippet below, in addition to the width, I've given it a display property of `inline-block` to ensure that it gets alloted width, and then `text-align: center` to ensure that the number stays in the center of available area.

```js
var valueS = $('.countSession')[0];
valueS.innerHTML = '0';

var valueS = $('.countSession')[0];
$("#minusS").click(function() {
  valueS.innerHTML--;
  if (valueS.innerHTML < 1) {
    valueS.innerHTML = '0';
  }
})


$("#plusS").click(function() {
  valueS.innerHTML++;
})
```

```css
.countSession {
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" id="minusS">-</button>

<span class="countSession"></span>

<button class="button" id="plusS">+</button>
```

Comment: It is probably better to set size in `em` instead of `px`. Also it is clear that instead use of `$()[0] .... innerHTML` author should use `$().text()`

Comment: @Flying That's a good point! If we are dealing with multiple fonts, it would be definitely better to define the width in em.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adjusting the three elements in an enclosing div and set it's width to however you feel best. I set it to `25%`. Then used `justify-content: space-between` to divide the elements properly. Check out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for more tricks with `CSS flexbox`.

```js
var valueS = $('.countSession')[0];
valueS.innerHTML = '0';

var valueS = $('.countSession')[0];
$("#minusS").click(function() {
  valueS.innerHTML--;
  if (valueS.innerHTML < 1) {
    valueS.innerHTML = '0';
  }
})


$("#plusS").click(function() {
  valueS.innerHTML++;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 25%; display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
    <button class="button" id="minusS" >-</button>

    <span class="countSession"></span>

    <button class="button" id="plusS" >+</button> 
</div>
```